# Exhibit an open cover of $E = \{ \frac{1}{n^2}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to look for an open cover for $E = \{ \frac{1}{n^2}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.  Would something like $(-\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q})$ work?

Furthermore, I have a different question about proving finite subcovers. For example, I know that for $\mathbb{N}$, an open cover would be $(-n, n)$, but how do I prove that this has no finite subcover? I'm guessing it has something to do with the archimedean property.

Comment: $E\subset (0,2)$-

Comment: One nice open cover for everything is $\{\mathbb R\}.$

Comment: The set $(-\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q})$ does not make sense. And the single set $(-n, n)$ cannot be a cover of $\mathbb{N}$ because it does not contain any integers greater than $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As regards the first question, I guess that the notation $(-\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q})$, which does not make sense, means the open cover given by the sets $(-q,q)$ for all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$. This is an open cover for ANY subset of $\mathbb{R}$!

Since $E$ is bounded, you can take also an open cover made of one set only. For instance, noting that $0<1/n^2<2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we find that $E\subset (0,2)$.

For the second question, assume that there exists a finite subcover and let $N$ be the largest positive integer such that $(-N,N)$ belongs to such subcover. Then we should conclude that $\mathbb{N}\subset (-N,N)$. Does this inclusion contradict the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)?